# Including own project code in fnproject function

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, libraries, fn

I'm working with [Fn Project](https://fnproject.io/) as part of Oracle Cloud Functions and I'm looking to include some helper functions that I wrote myself that are currently used in a few other programs. I'd like to include these functions without having to copy and paste them into my source code, and I feel like there's a way to do this that I haven't managed to find.

Here is what my directory structure looks like. Names have been changed to make it easier to understand.

```
- helper
  - foo.py
- other
  - example.py
- functions
  - myfunc
    - func.py
    - func.yaml
    - requirements.txt
```

Currently, in `example.py` I have the following:

```py
from helper import foo
...
foo.bar()
```

When I write func.py I write the same thing but when I run `fn deploy -app test_app` and then `fn invoke test_app myfunc` it errors out on the import statement (I ran the basic hello world function with `from helper import foo` at the top:

```
Error invoking function. status: 502 message: function failed
```

My first instinct was to put `helper` in the requirements.txt file but that only works with `pip` packages. How do I ensure that my own code is included?

Any help would be much appreciated!

---

### Update

So far my only solution has been to literally copy and paste my code into the source file, which is not very maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Once you do `from helper import foo` inside `func.py`, the entire code including the library import will be done in `func.py`. Using the command `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in your main directory, you can list all the dependent libraries of your project inside the `requirements.txt`. Hence when you create the docker image it will install everything from `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for this, perhaps my question wasn't clear enough - this is actually about the `foo` file I've written. Would it be included in the generated docker image - i.e. will `foo.bar()` work?

Comment: You have written `foo.bar()` inside `example.py` and this `bar()` function is present inside  `helper/foo.py` right? You will be generating a docker image of your entire project, which consists of all the files and hence all the .py files, functions inside that, libraries as in requirements. txt will be there.

Comment: Hi Aparna, I've updated the question. It doesn't include the function as it seems to be outside the scope of the Fn function.

Comment: I believe you are creating the docker image of functions folder (in case your project), but the functions you have used inside that is outside that and hence it won't be there in your docker image as per my understanding. If you want `foo.py` and `example.py` in that image the it must be in scope, ie. create a folder <Name> and then keep all these `helper, others and functions` inside that and create a docker image of <name>.

Comment: That's exactly right - is there any way you know of whereby I can include the helper functions - because I want to be able to use these functions in multiple docker images

Comment: Other than including these required .py files in your project, I am not sure how to make use of this for multiple docker images. If yo want to use the same code in multiple projects, then only way I can think of is creating an image of that common code. So that every project's docker container can interact with this common container. This is not at all a good solution, but I am not getting any other solution in my mind.

Comment: Thanks for that Aparna :)